# Refreshed Cache now rendering a mess

Tags: cache, magento-1.9.3.6

Had error bar in admin to refresh cache.  Did so and now site is down and rendering looks like Prodigy circa 1993.  Suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following will reindex each index.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```

You can also use the Magento collection model to load each index rather than hard coding the id in the for loop.

```
/* @var $indexCollection Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process_Collection */
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
    /* @var $index Mage_Index_Model_Process */
    $index->reindexAll();
}
```

But if you want to reindex just the price the id is 2

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(2);
$process->reindexAll();
```

You could also call the function getProcessByCode as follows:

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```

Please try the following code to flush the cache programatically

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache()
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the following :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy or
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: this question for magento 1